# Obfuscated code contains same member variable names

Tags: java, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have an obfuscated jar which is part of a deployed application in Tomcat on my machine. The jar consists of some weird code with same variable names. I used jshrink in order to decompile the code.

```
  static private org.apache.commons.logging.Log a;
  private org.springframework.context.MessageSource a;
  private org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor a;
  static private LicenseBean a;
  static private ThreadLocal a;
  private javax.servlet.ServletContext a;
  private String a;

  public LicenseBean() {
    a = null;
    a = null;
    a = this;
  }
```

Is it an issue with decompilation process? My question is how does JVM handle this if the decompilation process is correct?

Comment: This is not enough information to tell. It is not legal to use an identifier for two variables in Java. Maybe there is some Unicode magic involved.

Comment: @raphw May be there is some magic. The whole code consists of something like this. I was just curious to know how does JVM handle this.

Comment: The JVM would have no trouble at all handling references to identically-named private instance vars, since all references are by index.  But it may be that @raphw is correct and there are invisible characters present.

Comment: @Hot Licks Fields are not referenced by an index but by a name, this is also true for `private` fields. Thus, even `private` fields cannot share a name. This is additionally enforced by the contract of the reflection API and the native interface.

Comment: @raphw - Yeah, I forgot that the fieldref is symbolically linked to the field_info.  It's been 6-7 years since I was working on the verifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some obfuscators use control symbols for making identifiers harder to read. This concerns especially situations where code is printed to a console which interprets these symbols instead of printing their escaped icon. It could therefore be that these names are actually obfuscated as for example:

```
U+0061 U+200B * n
```

where `U+0061` represents `a` and `U+200B` is the zero-length width symbol which is entailed an incremented amount of times for each of the `n` identifiers. In a normal editor, all identifiers would then displayed as `a`.

In general, Java byte code does not allow duplicate identifiers for fields of a class but it allows identifiers which are not normal legal in Java source code. If your code runs, the Unicode theory is the most likely explanation. Maybe your decompiler also misses these characters or and they are not even put into the source code. Try to read the byte code (`javap` output) of the above class file with an editor which displays *invisible Unicode* to verify this theory.

Comment: "In general, Java byte code does not allow duplicate identifiers for fields of a class " -- this is not true! See https://www.benf.org/other/cfr/obfuscation_field_renaming.html: "BOTH name and descriptor (type information) are used for the JVM to uniquely identify a field. This means that according to the JVM, it's perfectly legitimate to have two fields of a different type with the same name."

Comment: That's true, Byte Buddy even supports that, but no JVM language I know of can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

That code is not valid Java code, it is possible that `jshrink` didn't manage to decompile the code correctly, the usual decompiler behavior is based on a *best-effort* technique.

Try to decompile it using [`CFR`](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/), it's a wonderful Java decompiler that usually produces valid code.

Comment: *blush* … and if CFR can't handle it, and you own it, submit it so I can fix it ;)