# Securing Java Application - Prevent classes from being patched

Tags: java, licensing, obfuscation, java-security

We are trying to secure a java application using a custom LicenseManager that gets called from different locations in our application.

The LicenseManager looks like this

```
public class LicenseManager {    
    public static void verify() {
        // throw Exception in case license is not valid
    }
}
```

Of course an easy way to "crack" the application would be to replace the LicenseManger with this one and prepend it to the classpath

```
public class LicenseManager {    
    public static void verify() {
        // NEVER throw an Exception!!!
    }
}
```

So to prevent the LicenseManager from being patched we added the following code to all parts of the application that call LicenseManager.verify():

```
    if (!LicenseManager.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().sameFile(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation())) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid license");
    }
```

This basically makes sure that the code source location of the LicenseManager and the code source of the remaining application are the same.

Does this make sense? Is there a way to still "hack" the LicenseManager with this approach?

EDIT:
We are also using Java String (https://jfxstore.com/stringer/) for string obfuscation and code IntegrityProtection. This makes it difficult to de-compile the application.

Also the call to LicenseManager.verify() is spread all over the application (hundreds of places!) so it would be a lot of work to modify all those places.

Comment: probably better suited on a security-related site. Sure there is a way. In general DRM is a nice idea that has nearly no practical use. In this case: just sign the code and verify the certificate, instead of comparing a few URLs. Circumventing the current way of verification would be extremely simple.

Comment: "_Is there a way to still "hack" the LicenseManager with this approach?_" Yes, there is. One could simply patch all places in your code where the license manager is called, and thus disable the check (would require decompiling your app or changing your code in some other way). Or use a customized JRE patched to always return true in `.sameFile(..)`. There's plenty of other ways too.

Comment: I dont really think there is a "hack" proof way to protect your program in java. You can try a combination of techniques, like the one you mentioned combined with some obfuscation disguising variable names to look exactly the same although they are not (More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262890/obfuscated-code-contains-same-member-variable-names) that can _prevent_ cracking to some extent but it is not a guarantee whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. I did add some more information to the original question. Regarding code signing, how would I do that? Would it be possible to just run the code without verifying the signature

Comment: Thanks @JonasCz! Please have a look at my EDIT of the original question. So replacing all calls to LicenseManager.verify() will be difficult I think!

Comment: @AndyFlury regarding code-signing: just google it, there are plenty of resources available on that topic. The certificate is just used to verify it's actually you who wrote the code. Disallow running code that wasn't signed by you and you should be a bitt more secure. Though in general: DRM is a deadend in a race vs. pirates. You're simply outpowered, since they have the binaries. You won't be able to achieve what microsoft and comparably large concerns can't achieve. Just make sure the average user can't circumvent it and rely on the honest of users. There isn't much else you can do

Comment: Thanks @Paul. I totally agree, there is no 100% security. We just want to make it hard for the average-user to hack the application. But of course a pro will always be able to do it. So maybe a combination of code signing, obfuscation & and verification of code source location (as mentioned in the question) make sense. Would you agree on that?

Comment: @AndyFlury that should do to keep anyone who isn't a dedicated hacker from cracking the software, yes.

Comment: @Paul, great! thanks for you advice!

Comment: @AndyFlury np, glad to help :)

Comment: Instead of prepending alternative implementations to the classpath, I there a reason one can't replace the .class file in the jar/folder/place it's in? That's how minecraft modding was done in the early days. Easy to do and no change in location.

Comment: *"spread all over the application (hundreds of places!) so it would be a lot of work to modify all those places."* for a human doing it manually. I'd try a few loops and a bytecode manipulation library.